# AlarmManager how to cancel repeating

Tags: android

```
private void scheduleAlarms(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intentOnAlaramReceiver = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentOnAlaramReceiver, 0);

        String listOfIntervalConnection = Utils.getStringFromProperties(context, Properties.SP_LIST_OF_ENABLE_INTERVAL_CONNECTIONS, Properties.ENABLE_AFTER);
        long enableAfter = DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS * Long.parseLong(listOfIntervalConnection);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + enableAfter, enableAfter, pendingIntent);
    }
```

and i try to cancel alarm like

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intentOnAlaramReceiver = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentOnAlaramReceiver, 0);

            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

but sometimne is canceled sometimes still working. Why and how? What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different instances of Intent in the PendingIntent when starting the service and while canceling it.

set the service intent as an instance variable and use it in both the starting and canceling of the service.

Comment: but if I want to cancel it after 1 day of running GC will remove the instance or not? Class is not available for ever,

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of 0; Like this:

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentOnAlaramReceiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```